# Uncaught TypeError: "utils.useControlled" is not a function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

An error occurred while rendering `Autocomplete` component from @material-ui/lab

material-ui versions:

- "@material-ui/core": "4.9.5",
- "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.45",

Comment: Please include code of how you implement this.

Comment: import React from 'react'
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'



export default function AutoCompleteMaterial (props) {
    return <Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={props.options}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
        style={{ width: 300,minWidth:200 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={props.name} variant="outlined" />}
    />
}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

It was due to a version mismatch between `@material-ui/core` and `@material-ui/lab`.
Precisely, you can check that `useControlled` only appears in [@material-ui/src/utils](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.0/packages/material-ui/src/utils/index.js) from version 4.9.0.
Could you verify in your `node_modules` that this function is well exported?

On my side, correctly upgrading the libs solved the problem.
Hope it helps